# Usergrid Portal 2.0.17 unable to login/register

Tags: authentication, registration, portal, usergrid

After countless hours of trial end error I finally figured out how to get cassandra 1.2 and usergrid 1.x up and running and talking to each other. "cassandraAvailable" : true, the keyspace has been created (by calling /system/database/setup and /system/superuser/setup). Then I installed Portal end see the login screen, but neither my sysadmin nor my test account, which I configured in usergrid-default.properties are accepted. Also I can not register a new user. It says "Error registering:" and nothing else.

Where can I look for error logging? What do I have to set to get Usergrid Portal working?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the correct URL to log into the portal, you will need to repeat the host twice so the portal knows what Usergrid instance you want to interact with.

```
http://[host]:8080/usergrid-portal/?api_url=http://[host]:8080
```

If you are running on Tomcat (make sure you are using Tomcat 7 for Usergrid 1.x) then you can look at the Tomcat logs for Usergrid issues.